# unity c# - How can I move a UI element to the direction of an object that is off the camera and constrain its position to be inside the UI?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi all and thank you for reading my issue.

Inside Unity, I'm trying to move the position of a RectTransform component of a UI element through a direction vector using a c# script and constrain its position to be inside the UI.

I tried to start solving this problem with the following approach:

```
public Transform objectToFollow;
public RectTransform imageToMove;

void Update()
{
    Vector3 objectPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(objectToFollow.position);
    imageToMove.position = objectPosition;
}
```

This script manages to move the position the RectTransform component when the object *is* being rendered by the camera, but it does not constrain the position of the RectTransform to be inside the UI, and that is what I am aiming at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by `inside the UI.` you mean inside the Screen you could do something like e.g. (not tested)

```
public Transform objectToFollow;
public RectTransform imageToMove;

private Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];

void Update()
{
    var objectPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(objectToFollow.position);

    // corners now contains the 4 screen space corners of the image
    // in order bottom left, top left, top right, bottom right. 
    imageToMove.GetWorldCorners(corners);

    // now you can clamp your position according to your corners and the screen dimensions
    var move = objectPosition - imageToMove.position;
    move.x = Mathf.Clamp(move.x, -corners[0].x, Screen.width - corners[3].x);
    move.y = Mathf.Clamp(move.y, -corners[0].y, Screen.height - corners[1].y);


    imageToMove.position += move;
}
```

what this does is basically comparing the current corners of your image to the screen borders and only allows to move so far that the corners overlap with the screen borders but not beyond.

If your image can be rotated you need an extra step for determining the min and max value for the x and y axes - right now I relied on the given order of the corners.

Could then probably also extend this also further to stay within another `RectTransform` by again also use [`GetWorldCorners`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html) also on that and compare the according values.

Comment: Thank you so much! That solves my problem, at least partially since once the objectToFollow is far off the camera, the WorldToScreenPoint does not return its right position, but I'll try to continue from here.